jQuery ajax post request on ASP.NET Core MVC with application/json
I'm trying to make and ajax call using jQuery.ajax and contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
I created a new project for ASP.NET Core MVC with .NET 8.
This is the Javascript code:
$('#addPerson').click(function () {
    var person = {
        Name: 'Test1',
        Email: 'Test2'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddPerson")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ person: person }),
        // data: { person: person },
        type: 'Post',
        success: function (data) {
            
        }
    });
});

Here is the controller method and the model:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPerson(Person person)
{
    return Ok();
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

For some reason the person's properties are always null.
If I comment the lines shown below in the ajax call
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: JSON.stringify({ person: person }),

and uncomment the line shown below then I can see properties filled in the controller correctly.
// data: { person: person },

Also if I add [FromBody] in my controller parameter and change the data to JSON.stringify(person), it still works but I don't want that since in many cases I may need to send to controller a whole person object and then additional parameters.
In previous versions in ASP.NET MVC, I believe this was working. My guess is that I have to specify a serializer in program.cs to make it work. But I tried different variations without success.

can you elaborate what is the question here? what contenttype do you want to use and how do you want the controller to bind the data?

I want to use application/json; charset=utf-8 and the data being for example the person viewmodel we see and additional parameters. So the controller will have a parameter person and perhaps other bool parameters. I used the exact example in asp.net mvc and it works. But on asp.net core it doesn't. The only way I made it work is with [FromBody] attribute which I don't like.

i think [FromBody] is needed to read json though. If you omit the contentType (default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8") and send plain object in data you can get rid of [FromBody]

Yes that what I stay in my example as well. It works this way. But in asp.net mvc it works both ways without [FromBody]. I wonder what fundamentally changed in .net core and can't make it work without [FromBody].

When you specify contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', you're telling the server that the data being sent in the request body is in JSON format. ASP.NET Core's default model binder expects the JSON data to match the parameter of the action method exactly if you're not using [FromBody].In ASP.NET Core, the [FromBody] attribute explicitly tells the model binder to look for data in the request body and try to bind it to the action method's parameter. Without [FromBody], model binding looks at various sources including the query string and form data, but it has specific expectations about the request body that often require [FromBody] for JSON data.Your AJAX call is sending data in a nested object format: { person: person }. However, your action method expects a flat Person object. This is the reaosn why your properties are coming across as null when you use JSON.stringify({ person: person }) without [FromBody].
You could try this below code to resolve the issue:
 $('#addPerson').click(function () {
    var person = {
        Name: 'Test1',
        Email: 'Test2'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddPerson")' + '?additionalParam=true', //additional parameters
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(person), // Send person object directly
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            // success
        }
    });
});

Controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPerson([FromBody] Person person, [FromQuery] bool additionalParam)
{
    // Your Code
    return Ok();
}

You need to use [FromBody] to bind the JSON body to your model

I understand that your code works. My question is if you can do the request without the need of creating the PersonRequest class. Can you achieve the same result with contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' while having in controller method:
public IActionResult AddPerson(Person person, bool additionalParam).
As I said earlier I manages to do it successfully in asp.net but not in asp.net-core.

@ThemisTsiligkoudis could you try updated code.

I tried your code and it works. But I don't like that approach either. I don't want to create separate classes each time I want additional parameters. I also don't want to work with dynamic objects and deserialization. I want to have the model parameter and the additional parameters straight on the controller method. Is this a limitation of .net core? Because as I said in older version of asp.net mvc this works fine

@ThemisTsiligkoudis In ASP.NET Core, handling JSON data requires explicitly using the [FromBody] attribute due to a design philosophy emphasizing clear separation of concerns and greater control over data binding. Unlike older ASP.NET MVC versions, ASP.NET Core's model binder does not infer data sources based on content type. For mixed data types (JSON + other sources), combining [FromBody] for JSON with other attributes like [FromQuery] for additional parameters is recommended. This approach reflects ASP.NET Core's focus on explicitness and flexibility.

You can use JObject from NuGetpackage and use namespace "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq", but still you may want to use [FromBody] Attribute:
public IActionResult AddPerson([FromBody] JObject objRequest)
{
    Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(objRequest.ToString());
    string phone = objRequest.Value<string>("phone");  // additional field extraction
    // you can add any other fields to objRequest (Request Body) and only those matching fields will be automatically bind to Person object
    return Ok();
}


Well this is doable I guess but having the parameters in the controller is way more straightforward. As I said this works if don't send it with application/json. I would love to know what is the issue here because I tried the template for asp.net mvc with .net 4.7.2 and the initial code works without any issue
